# python3 NamedTemporaryFile much slower for writing than a normal file on gcloud instance

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, temporary-files

I used the code below to tar a folder about 1G. It takes more than **30s** to finish

```
import tarfile
import tempfile

# tar the folder
tmp_path = 'my_folder'

f_temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
src_fname = f_temp.name
with tarfile.open(src_fname, "w") as tar:
    tar.add(tmp_path, arcname='.')
```

However, if I use `tar cf my_folder` in terminal, it only takes a little more than a second.

If I use a normal file, the python script also takes less than 2 seconds.

```
import tarfile

# tar the folder
tmp_path = 'my_folder'

src_fname = 'nos.tar'
with tarfile.open(src_fname, "w") as tar:
    tar.add(tmp_path, arcname='.')
```

Why is the speed so different? In my case, both the temporary file and the `nos.tar` are written to the same device `/dev/sda1`. The computer is a google cloud `n1-standard-4/nvidia-tesla-v100/1` instance in `us-central1-a`.

This slowdown seems to be related to the gcloud instance. I tried the aforementioned 3 methods on my local computer, i.e.,

- `tar cf nos.tar my_folder`
- use regular file
- use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`

All of them finish within 2 seconds. The second method is slower than the first one for about 0.4 seconds, and the third one is slower than the first one for about 0.4 seconds, which is mentioned in [the other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103422/namedtemporaryfile-speed-underwhelming).

On the gcloud instance, the `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` is in `/tmp` and I wrote regular file to `/scratch`.

```
nos@instance:/scratch$ df -h /scratch/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        31G  2.2G   29G   7% /
nos@instance:/scratch$ df -h /tmp/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        31G  2.2G   29G   8% /
```

Both point to the same device, but the speed seem to indicate different devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NamedTemporaryFile speed underwhelming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103422/namedtemporaryfile-speed-underwhelming)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The slowdown is more significant than the other case, and is specific to the gcloud instance.

Comment: Not of much help, but with "python3 -m cProfile" you will see that the difference is on {method 'close' of '_io.BufferedWriter' objects} and we don't have access to _io.

Comment: Also you can adventure yourself with "strace -T -e openat,close python3 my_script0.py " and check that for the first script the close call that takes up the most time is on the "/tmp/tmp*" while for the second is on the "nos.tar". Now why? Too advanced for me.